# Why Homebrew is connecting to Google analytics and how to disable it?

Tags: homebrew

I've noticed that when I run :

```
brew update
```

Homebrew is connecting to Google analytics. Why? And how to disable it?

Answer (score 10):

According to the official documentation : [Anonymous Aggregate User Behaviour Analytics](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Analytics.md)

> Homebrew has begun gathering anonymous aggregate user behaviour analytics and reporting these to Google Analytics. You will be notified the first time you run brew update or install Homebrew.
>   Why?
>
> Homebrew is provided free of charge and run entirely by volunteers in their spare time. As a result, we do not have the resources to do detailed user studies of Homebrew users to decide on how best to design future features and prioritise current work. Anonymous aggregate user analytics allow us to prioritise fixes and features based on how, where and when people use Homebrew.

You can disable this feature with :

```
brew analytics off
```

or by setting

```
export HOMEBREW_NO_ANALYTICS=1
```

Answer (score -2):

The [anonymizing flag is hardcoded as enabled](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/HEAD/Library/Homebrew/utils/analytics.rb#L34), the [Google Analytics anonymous IP setting](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#aip), with further remarks:

> It is impossible for the Homebrew developers to match any particular
> event to any particular user, even if we had access to the Homebrew
> analytics user ID (which we do not).
>
> As far as we can tell it would be impossible for Google to match the
> randomly generated Homebrew-only analytics user ID to any other Google
> Analytics user ID. If Google turned evil the only thing they could do
> would be to lie about anonymising IP addresses and attempt to match
> users based on IP addresses.

But the only solution is to use a firewall. It's been normalized for most apps to track everything from heat maps to the people at Google trying to the your formulae collection fingerprint to your next online purchase.

[image: Arguments and flags won't help with porous borders getting penetrated and charted.]